# MVC Intellisense and Recipe not working on a converted webforms project

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-2, asp.net-mvc-4, webforms

I followed the instructions on the following link to convert our webforms project to MVC

http://www.hanselman.com/blog/IntegratingASPNETMVC3IntoExistingUpgradedASPNET4WebFormsApplications.aspx

However, intellisense and syntax highlighting are not working on the cshtml views. Also recipes such as "Create new Area" etc. does not work on the converted project. All these things are working in the "pure" mvc-4 project.

Does anyone have a clue on what I might be missing?

Answer (score 1):

Open the `.csproj` file in a text editor and make sure that `{39613BA0-1206-4A4B-A16A-C1F2A22D1267}` appears in the `<ProjectTypeGuids>` element.

This GUID tells VIsual Studio to add MVC menu items.

Comment: It was a Guid, but it was the project type Guid, but this helped my colleague and I down the right path. We did a diff of the <ProjectType> node and copy over the difference. That did the trick on the area.

Answer (score 0):

My colleague did a diff between the MVC4 project template we downloaded and the existing project being upgraded.

We merged the  Guids, and that got the recipes working.

He also found the intellisense solution [here](http://forums.asp.net/t/1774792.aspx/1):

Except that ours was version 2.0.0.0 instead of 1.0.0.0 (to match the reference in the .csproj include)